# Install Metron on Ubuntu 14 fail vagrant Ubuntu

Tags: metron

[Install Metron step by step](https://metron.apache.org/current-book/metron-deployment/development/ubuntu14/index.html) but fail

Env:

```
root@ubuntu:~/metron# metron-deployment/scripts/platform-info.sh
Metron 0.7.2
--
* master
--
commit bb9a244d81feb54bc93456310f57a92d63cea38f (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: tiborm <tibor.meller@gmail.com>
Date:   Sat Oct 12 15:17:40 2019 -0500

    METRON-2259 [UI] Hide Resolved and Hide Dismissed toggles not works when filtering is in manual mode (tiborm via sardell) closes apache/metron#1532
--
 metron-deployment/development/ubuntu14/Vagrantfile | 3 ++-
 1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
--
ansible 2.5.1
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15+ (default, Oct  7 2019, 17:39:04) [GCC 7.4.0]
--
Vagrant 2.2.6
--
vagrant-hostmanager (1.8.9, global)
--
Python 2.7.15+
--
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: /root/apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_231, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jdk1.8.0_231/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-46-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
--
Docker version 18.09.7, build 2d0083d
--
node
v8.10.0
--
npm
3.5.2
--
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

--
Compiler is C++11 compliant
--
Linux ubuntu 4.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 6 09:33:07 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
--
Total System Memory = 16041 MB
Processor Model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E7-4820 v4 @ 2.00GHz
Processor Speed: 2000.000 MHz
Total Physical Processors: 4
Total cores: 4
Disk information:
/dev/sda1       493G   24G  448G   6% /
This CPU appears to support virtualization
```

I run `vagrant --ansible-skip-tags="build" provision` because download Ambari timeout when use `vagrant up`. And add

```
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 4201, host: 4201
```

Get ERROR:

```
TASK [java_jdk : Update package cache] *****************************************
changed: [node1]

TASK [java_jdk : Install openjdk] **********************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [ambari_config : include_vars] ********************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [ambari_config : include_tasks] *******************************************

TASK [ambari_config : Wait for Ambari to start; http://node1:8080] *************
ok: [node1]

TASK [ambari_config : Deploy cluster with Ambari; http://node1:8080] ***********
 [WARNING]: Module did not set no_log for password

ok: [node1]

PLAY [ambari_master] ***********************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [epel : Install EPEL repository] ******************************************
skipping: [node1]

TASK [python-pip : Install Python's pip on Centos] *****************************
skipping: [node1]

TASK [python-pip : Install Python's pip on Ubuntu] *****************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [httplib2 : Install python httplib2 dependency] ***************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [ambari_gather_facts : Ask Ambari: cluster_name] **************************
skipping: [node1]

TASK [ambari_gather_facts : set_fact] ******************************************
skipping: [node1]

TASK [ambari_gather_facts : set_fact] ******************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [ambari_gather_facts : Ask Ambari: namenode_host] *************************
changed: [node1]

TASK [ambari_gather_facts : set_fact] ******************************************
ok: [node1]

TASK [ambari_gather_facts : Ask Ambari: core_site_tag] *************************
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "curl -s -u admin:admin -X GET -H \"X-Requested-By: ambari\" 'http://node1:8080/api/v1/clusters/metron_cluster/hosts/node1/host_components/NAMENODE' | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)[\"HostRoles\"][\"actual_configs\"][\"core-site\"][\"default\"]'", "delta": "0:00:00.137241", "end": "2019-10-23 11:29:26.165880", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2019-10-23 11:29:26.028639", "stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>\nKeyError: 'core-site'", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"<string>\", line 1, in <module>", "KeyError: 'core-site'"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
    to retry, use: --limit @/root/metron/metron-deployment/development/ubuntu14/ansible/playbook.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
node1                      : ok=90   changed=26   unreachable=0    failed=1

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

Comment: what does this have to do with Apache httpd (your tag)?

Comment: @OlafKock I'm a newbie in big data. I don't know why get this error and how to solve， so I give all info what I can give. I can't find wiki on apache metron github, so I only ask my question here. May be  official apache metron have bug in vagrant script :) .  I can't find where `httpd` you metion?

Comment: the tag information for "apache" contained this. I've re-tagged, hope that hadoop is related to your question as metron seems to be related to hadoop.

Comment: Oh I misunderstand you before. OK I see. I've fix my tag for my question.

Comment: fyi, I've created metron as a new tag - there is nobody yet monitoring this tag, and you might want to think of a *matching* additional tag. There are a bunch of topical ones - just "apache", the httpd-server, was so unrelated that any traffic from that tag wouldn't have helped anyway

Comment: Oh, I cloud not find `metron` tag before you created . Thanks your created.
I didn't notice that `apache` just related to http server not the Apache Foundation